# Query String with error "invalid literal for int() with base 10"

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I was trying to get a Model object from datastore using the key passed from query string. It worked before that, however, recently, when I named the file from restaurantProfile.html to restaurant_profile.html. I don't know from which part went wrong caused the problem.

My restaurant key should contains the key. However, from the GAE log, I've set custom debug to see what contains in Restaurant key passed to my handler (Result):

```
GAE Log:
Restaurant Key = <bound method Restaurant.key of <persistence.model.Restaurant object at 0x5cd3c5acd5768900>>
```

Can anyone tell me what's got wrong here? The restaurant key doesn't seem to be passed to the handler.

```
<a href="/restaurant_profile?restaurant_key={{ key }}">
```

Handler Class:

```
class RestaurantProfileHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    restaurant_key = self.request.GET.get(u'restaurant_key')

    logging.debug('Restaurant Key = %s', restaurant_key)
```

Error: "invalid literal for int() with base 10" for following:

```
def get_RestaurantDetails(restaurant_key):
   if restaurant_key:
       restaurant = db.Key.from_path('Restaurant', int(restaurant_key))
       return db.get(restaurant)
```

Code to retrieve the key:

```
for restaurant in foundRestaurants:
            result_data[restaurant.key] = restaurant
```

Problem solved by following:

```
 key = restaurant.key().__str__()
            result_data[key] = restaurant
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where the key is generated ? Your logfile says that you passed a method to you template, not the key as an integer. Maybe you forgot some "()" when generating the key.

Comment: @rocksportrocker, this is the weird part. It works before. And the restaurant object is valid because it can be displayed on result page. On the result page, it calls the page that I wanted to pass the key on. I've added the code on the last section.

Comment: @rocksportrocker, you are right. The key was wrongly passed. Because this development updated through GitHub, so that part wasn't done by me. But, I realized the key was wrong from the part where it generates the key. Good Catch for that! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by following:

```
 key = restaurant.key().__str__()
            result_data[key] = restaurant
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me what's got wrong here?

it's exactly like it says: `restaurant_key` is a method. You can't call `int()` upon that; did you mean to call `int()` upon the *result of calling* `restaurant_key()`?

As for why `restaurant_key` is a method, well, that's what `self.request.GET.get(u'restaurant_key')` returned. Maybe you should re-read the documentation...